# General php format

Tags: php

So, I am just familiarizing myself with php and I see that there are few alternative formats when it comes to writing in php.

What I am confused about is the "dots" or their placements as well other stuffs such as "_".

For example,

```
<?php
    if(!empty($my_post))
    {
    echo $my_post . ' ' . __('my_post','my_site') . ' + ';
    } 
?>
```

It might be a really silly question but could someone explain to me what the function of "dots" in between and just the format itself.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: It simply concatenates or combines the values of the declared variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TheSaurus has answered it right. Dots(.) in PHP are the concatenation operators like that plus(+) in java. Whenever you want to build a string with some sub strings, you may use it. There are several other plenty of uses of this, depending on the use.Like One explained in above example.
e.g.:

```
$line="STACK OVERFLOW";
echo "$line<br/>"
// Some Computation
$line.="is good"; // Here used to concatenate
echo $line
```

This will output

```
STACK OVERFLOW
STACK OVERFLOW is good
```

Answer (score 1):

Dots are string concatenation operators in PHP.

So, if I write

```
$a="3";
$b="text";
echo $a.$b;
```

The result will be 3text.
If you want to add some space between those;

```
echo $a.' '.$b;
```

The result will be 3 text.
Please note that ' ' means space character in string form.

Also, please check other questions before submitting one.

Answer (score 1):

The dot is the concatenation operator ('.'), which returns the concatenation of its right and left arguments.

```
<?php

    $var = "hello";
    $world = "world";

    echo "$var" . '$world'; //outputs hello$world

    echo "$var" . "$world"; //outputs helloworld

    echo "$var" .  $world; //outputs helloworld

    ?>
```

[Read More](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Answer (score 1):

**The dot**

As many have answered before, the dot concatenates strings into a single string. But it's not necessary for bot to be strings. You can concatenate an integer with a string just fine.

```
<?php 
$a = 'Number';
$b = 2;
$c = 'Yay!';

echo $a . $b . $c; // Output: Number2Yay!
?>
```

---

**The double underscore**

In your case, the __() function is just an alias for `gettext()`: documentation: [LINK](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php)

Usually, though, the double underscore is used for Magic Methods.

You'll find this piece of text in the documentation:

> PHP reserves all function names starting with __ as magical. It is recommended that you do not use function names with __ in PHP unless you want some documented magic functionality.

You can read all about them here: [Magic Methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)

P.S. You'll probably find [THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php) very useful for future reference. I really recommend looking through this list :)